# Alterar um date input quando mudar o select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Gostaria que se usuário selecionar uma opção específica de um select no formulario como a segunda opção outro campo do tipo data do mesmo formulário mude para a data de hoje automaticamente.

```
<input type="date" id="demoInput" /> 

<select id="demoSelect" />
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

$('#demoSelect').change(function(){
    $('#demoInput').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Leitura recomendada: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Answer (score 1):

O seu código funciona corretamente, o problema é que um input do tipo data só recebe valores no formato de data. Mude o value das options para datas no formato `yyyy-mm-dd` e funcionará normal.

```js
$('#demoSelect').change(function(){
    $('#demoInput').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="demoInput" /> 

<select id="demoSelect" />
<option value="2019-01-01">01/01/2019</option>
<option value="2018-02-01">01/02/2018</option>
<option value="2017-12-05">05/12/2017</option>
</select>
```